# disconnected subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Say I have a subset $U\subset X$  and $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $U$ is disconnected, is it necessary that X is disconnected as well?

What if I remove $X\subset \mathbb{R}$?

I have a feeling that it will be yes in both case but I am failing to see it straight from the definition.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Suppose that $X$ is $\mathbb R$ itself. Then $X$ is connected.